# Pubnub get all messages of all channels in a group in single stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

In Pubnub channel groups feature , how can I get all the messages of all the channels in the group as mentioned [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/advanced-channel-groups)

"*if you subscribe to the Channel Group, you get all messages from all the channels in the group in a single stream*"

I couldn't find any API to get all the messages of all the channels of a group in a single API call.

Comment: So, what was meant by 'getting all messages in a single stream'

Comment: The description in the link above I mentioned is somewhat deceiving, the channel group has nothing to do with the fetching of messages

Comment: Thanks @CraigConover , this clears my doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Channel Groups: Receive vs Fetch Messages

*Single stream* just means you can subscribe to a channel group which in turn means you are subscribed to all the channels in that channel group (up to 200 channels total). And you can subscribe to 10 total channel groups per client for a total of 20K channels. The single stream which it refers to is the connection to PubNub. One connection (stream), up to 20K total channels.

With PubNub, you don't fetch messages, you receive them in realtime when they are published. But if you truly meant *fetch* messages that have already been published but the client was not connected at the time, then yes, you need to call `history` to get *old* messages.

But the link you provided says nothing about *fetching* messages. It talks about subscribing to channel groups to receive messages from many different channels (friends' channels, in that design pattern) in realtime, not fetching old messages.